# Is there any way of making a model Relationship with an array of ids

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

Does anyone know how to make a relationship where foreign key is an array of ids instead of one ID?

Sample Controller:

```
$products = Products::with('productCategory')->get();
```

Model Relationship:

```
public function productCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(productCategory::class, 'product_category_id', 'id');
}
```

Product Table:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Mango',
        'product_category_id': ['1', '2']
    }
]
```

Product Categories table:

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Food'
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Fruits'
    }
]
```

Comment: Is it possible, Yes, should you do it, No, You really shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

No. From a MySQL perspective, it wouldn't work. If there is a foreign key relationship, then the local key (i.e. product_category_id on the products table) must match exactly the foreign key (i.e. id on the product_categories table) in every respect. You cannot match an array to an integer.

If you need an instance of one model to be related to many different instances of a different model, then you don't need to reinvent the wheel, you can just use Laravel's Many to Many relationship (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) because, presumably, a product can be in multiple categories, and a category can have multiple products.